# The existence of the set of all functions on A into B

Tags: set-theory

I need to prove that the set of all functions on A into B, denoted by $B^{A}$, exists.

I think if $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$ then $|B^{A}|=n^{m}$ because for each element of $A$ there are $n$ independent ways of mapping it to $B$.

I don't know how to prove this.

the last time I posted this questions it got negative votes and closed.

It is a question, asked in Hrbacek and Jechs book.  I need to answer it.  Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ and $B$ exist, thus $A \times B$ exists, so $\mathcal{P}(A \times B)$ exists. Thus by the [schema of separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_separation) (aka the schema of comprehension), we have that $$\{f \in \mathcal{P}(A \times B) : f \mbox{ is a function } A \rightarrow B\}$$

exists. But this is just $B^A$, by definition. So we're done.

Note that I am using the statement

$$f \mbox{ is a function } A \rightarrow B$$

as shorthand for the statement

$$\forall a \in A,\exists! b \in B : (a,b) \in f.$$

This usage, while convenient, is non-standard. In particular, in most other branches of mathematics we take $f : A \rightarrow B$ to mean that $f$ has source $A$ and target $B$.

Comment: Using the usual FOL quantifiers, that shorthand would be: $$\forall a (a\in A \rightarrow \exists b (b\in B \wedge (a,b)\in f))\wedge \forall a,b_1,b_2 ((a,b_1)\in f \wedge (a,b_2)\in f \rightarrow b_1=b_2)$$

Comment: @DanChristensen, thank you. In retrospect, I should have included that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument doesn't explain why the set exists, and it doesn't suggest what to do if one of the sets is infinite.

Now that every function from $B$ to $A$ is a subset of $B\times A$. Show that we can define when a set is a function whose domain is $B$ (where $B$ is a parameter), then you can use separation to conclude the set of functions is a subset of $\mathcal P(B\times A)$.

Comment: I am looking for the existence of all functions ON A INTO B, this means domain = A and range $\subseteq$ B.  I know I need to show that $B^{A} \subseteq P(A \times B)$ I don't know how to go about it.  I don't know what you mean by "use separation".  I'm taking an intro to set theory course :(

Comment: Sarah, separation means that we can define it as a subset of a set which exists. In other words, we already know it will be a subset of a set, so we just need to write the defining property of the elements of that set.

Comment: It seems that Hrbacek and Jech use the name "comprehension" instead of "separation".